# g_main_loop never returns

Tags: c, glib, gegl

I am using `Gegl` to render some output and to create a window and `GLib` to create an event loop. The problem I am struggling with is that the `g_main_loop_run()` function never returns (that is when I close the application widow (or hit Alt+F4), the code after it is not reached at all).

A minimal example, that I made up:

```
#include <gegl.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gegl_init(&argc, &argv);

  GeglNode *gegl = gegl_node_new();
  GeglNode *text = gegl_node_new_child(gegl,
                                       "operation", "gegl:text",
                                       "size", 100.0,
                                       "color", gegl_color_new ("rgb(1.0,1.0,1.0)"),
                                       "string", "Hello",
                                       NULL);
  GeglNode *display = gegl_node_new_child(gegl,
                                          "operation", "gegl:display",
                                          NULL);

  gegl_node_link(text, display);
  gegl_node_process(display);

  GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, 0);

  printf("before\n");
  g_main_loop_run(loop);
  // the code from here on never executes
  printf("after\n");

  g_main_loop_unref(loop);

  g_object_unref(gegl);

  gegl_exit();

  return 0;
}
```

The code from line that says `printf("after\n");` and on never executes. Another thing that I observed was that when I used `g_timeout_add_seconds()` and set up a callback, which called the `g_main_loop_quit`, then the `g_main_loop_run` correctly returned and program continued as I would have expected. I also tried to use `gtk_main()`, but it behaved the same.

I suppose, the problem will be in some setting, that I failed to pass to `GMainLoop`, but I haven't found anything on Google, or in documentation ...

Comment: I havn't used gegl before. But going by gtk (which is similar). You don't seem to have any callback from the window being destoryed. Within the callback you would put the command to quite the loop (gtk_main_quit in gtk's case).
When you close the window, I should think the program is actually still running in the background if you check the task manager.

Comment: I checked `Applications -> System Tools -> System monitor` and my program was not listed there.

Comment: Well just looking at it from here, if using g_timeout_add_seconds to a callback fixed the problem. That would suggest to me you just need to link a signal event to quit the program to that callback with the g_main_loop_quit command.

Answer (score 1):

g_main_loop_run(loop); is a blocking call. typically it is run at the end of the application as a main event loop or in a seperate thread. so you add sources at first and do a loop run at the end so it polls on the sources and executes the callback